# I have a Spinner field in custom layout of adapter. problem to load data position wise

Tags: android

Code

```
AuthorlistSpinnerAdapter authorlistSpinnerAdapter = new AuthorlistSpinnerAdapter (context, booksDetailsArrayList);
holder.spinner_product_details.setAdapter(authorlistSpinnerAdapter );
```

[image]

Comment: I have a custom layout(grid) with spinner and text filed. 
I have done the booklist in grid with name in the textfield but cannot load the data(Aname) of bookdetails  in the spinner with position.

Comment: Hi, You need to implement custom views, and parent item must have to recyclerview
Nested Recyclerview, parent Recyclerview and child Recylerview

Comment: You need help for codding? i can also do for you

Comment: I have done in recycler too but the problem to load the spinner data from bookdetails arraylist with the particular position. loaded the same data in every spinner. Any help?

Comment: you are using Resyclerview and every item using Spinner Right?

Comment: How to load that bookdetailsArraylist in that spinner.

Comment: ok Just 1 mint i am sending you code

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**
     *
     */
    private void showMakeDialog() {
        if (mValuationParametersData == null) {
            getParameters(true);
            return;
        }

        String make = LiteralsStr.BUY_SELECT_MAKE;

        final List<AttributeUI> attributeUIList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Make> makeList = mValuationParametersData.getMakes();
        for (int i = 0; i < makeList.size(); i++) {
            AttributeUI attributeUI = new AttributeUI();
            attributeUI.setAttributeStr(makeList.get(i).getName());
            attributeUIList.add(attributeUI);
        }

        SpinnerDialogFragment fragment = SpinnerDialogFragment.getInstance(mMakePosition, make, attributeUIList, new SpinnerItemCheckListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckChange(int position) {
                mMakePosition = position;
                mMakeId = mValuationParametersData.getMakes().get(position).getId();
                mBinding.edtMake.edtAttribute.setText(attributeUIList.get(position).getAttributeStr());
                mBinding.edtModel.edtAttribute.setText("");
                mBinding.edtYear.edtAttribute.setText("");
                mModelPosition = -1;
                mYearPosition = -1;
            }
        });
        fragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }



public class SpinnerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static final String TAG = SpinnerDialogFragment.class.getCanonicalName();

    private static List<AttributeUI> mAttributeUIList;
    private SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter;
    private static SpinnerItemCheckListener spinnerItemCheckListener;
    private RecyclerView rvSpinner = null;
    private TextView tvCancel, tvDone, tvTitle;
    private static String mTitle = "";
    private static int mPosition = -1;

    public static SpinnerDialogFragment getInstance(int position, String pTitle, List<AttributeUI> pAttributeUIList, SpinnerItemCheckListener pSpinnerItemCheckListener) {
        mPosition = position;
        mTitle = pTitle;
        mAttributeUIList = pAttributeUIList;
        spinnerItemCheckListener = pSpinnerItemCheckListener;
        SpinnerDialogFragment fragment = new SpinnerDialogFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_app_spinner, container);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        // Alert Dialog cancelable false.
        setCancelable(true);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        rvSpinner = (RecyclerView) (view).findViewById(R.id.rvSpinner);
        tvCancel = (TextView) (view).findViewById(R.id.tvCancel);
        tvCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvDone = (TextView) (view).findViewById(R.id.tvDone);
        tvDone.setOnClickListener(this);

        tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvTitle.setText(mTitle);

        tvDone.setText(LiteralsStr.CHANGE_PASSWORD_DONE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        rvSpinner.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mSpinnerAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter(mAttributeUIList, new SpinnerItemCheckListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckChange(int position) {
                mPosition = position;
            }
        });
        rvSpinner.setAdapter(mSpinnerAdapter);

        smoothScroll();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.tvCancel:
                dismiss();
                break;

            case R.id.tvDone:
                if (mPosition == -1) {
                    Util.showToastMsg(getActivity(), getString(R.string.please) + mTitle);
                    return;
                }
                if (spinnerItemCheckListener != null)
                    spinnerItemCheckListener.onCheckChange(mPosition);
                dismiss();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void smoothScroll() {
        if (mPosition < 0)
            return;

        rvSpinner.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(mPosition);
        mAttributeUIList.get(mPosition).setSelected(true);
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:alpha="0.85"
        android:background="@color/colorGray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_view_blue_top"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/_12sdp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_10sdp">

            <com.ecomplanners.topcar.customfontview.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
                app:customFont="@string/HelveticaNeueLTStd_65_Medium"
                tools:text="Title" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvSpinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorTransparent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:fadeScrollbars="true"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:scrollIndicators="none"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_app_spinner" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <com.ecomplanners.topcar.customfontview.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCancel"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:background="@drawable/bottom_left_rounded_rectangle_gray"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:text="@string/cancel"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlue"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:customFont="@string/HelveticaNeueLTStd_65_Medium" />

            <com.ecomplanners.topcar.customfontview.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDone"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:background="@drawable/bottom_right_rounded_rectangle_blue"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:text="@string/done"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:customFont="@string/HelveticaNeueLTStd_65_Medium" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

[image][image]

Comment: I think this will help you 100%

Comment: if you even not able to implement i can help you more ...
thanks

Comment: You cant get my question actually

Comment: See I  have posted the json data... there are two array one is booklist another one is bookdetails. in booklist there are multiple books and under each books  bookdetails are there. Mainly aname. 
Now, in a custom layout one testview and another one is spinner. i have done with the booklist in textview. but not able to load spinner data for each book in the same custom layout.

Comment: Send me API i will send you code with implementation thanks

Comment: {
"BookList": [
{
"bookid":"1",
"bookname":"Physics",
"Bookdetails": [
{
"id":"1",
"Aname":"DMM"
},
{
"id":"3",
"Aname":"Modern ABC"
}
]
},
{
"bookid":"90",
"bookname":"Maths",
"Bookdetails":[

{
"id":"768",
"Aname":"Arihant"
},
{
"id":"09",
"Aname":"Dinesh"
}
]
},{
"bookid":"80",
"bookname":"Chem",
"Bookdetails":[
{
"id":"123",
"Aname":"MTR"
},
{
"id":"156",
"Aname":"Arihant"
}
]
}]
}

Comment: Check this in json parser and I have add data
                                                bookDetailsArrayList.add(new BookDetails(id, name));
                                        BookListArrayList.add(new BookList(bookid, bookname,bookDetailsArrayList));

Comment: What is Design of Screen

Comment: When you need this Maximum?

Comment: Its a grid view in main.xml and in custom_layout there are textview and spinner.